# Multiple Properties.Setting in C#

Tags: c#, settings.settings

I have added more settings to c# project. i have Settings.settings, Settings1.settings, ... each of those have same value settings of many types..
id - string, point - Point(), size - Size() 
but different values.

example:

Settings.settings has data:

`id = 'first'; string
point = 10@10; Point()
size = 111; 111; Size()`

Settings1.settings has data:

`id = 'second'; string
point = 20@20; Point()
size = 222; 222; Size()`

I choose which settings the program will be using at start (by choosing id of setting from listbox).

I then want to get settings value for selected setting with:

```
Object myPoint = Config.currentPropertiesAt("point");

/Config class/ -> public static Object currentPropertiesAt(string value)
```

How can i get that value here from correct Settings?

How can i know what object type it will get returned? That is why i use Object, but this can not be OK.

What is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to create an Interface ISettings containing all the settings that you will need:

```
interface ISettings
{
    string Id { get;  }
    Point Point { get;  }
    Size Size { get;  }

    ...
}
```

Then define partial classes that will match your generated Settings classes:

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : ISettings { }
internal sealed partial class Settings1 : ISettings { }
internal sealed partial class Settings2 : ISettings { }
...
```

Because your generated `Settings1.Designer.cs` classes implement the actual interface, there is nothing more to add here.

Now, in your code you can always reference ISettings to get to the value of your settings:

```
var currentSettings = Config.CurrentSettings; // returns ISettings
var id = currentSettings.Id;
```

In the code where you wish to select which settings (1,2, ...) to use (I assume this is in your Config class) you return the correct class:

```
class Config
{
    // Select the correct object using a string, or enum, or int, or ...
    public static ISettings SetCurrentSettings(string selectedSettings)
    {
        switch (selectedSettings)
        {
            default:
            case "Settings":
                CurrentSettings = Properties.Settings.Default;
                break;
            case "Settings1":
                CurrentSettings = Properties.Settings1.Default;
                break;
            case "Settings2":
                CurrentSettings = Properties.Settings2.Default;
                break;
        }
        return CurrentSettings;
    }
    public static ISettings CurrentSettings { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: `interface ISettings
    {
        public string siteName { get; }
        public string someValue { get; }
    }` gives me Error for both of them :The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item.
also: (Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'xxx.ISettings' is less accessible than method 'xxx.Config.SetCurrentSettings(string)')

Comment: ok..it works. learned a lot about stuff i didn't use, noob as i am. interfaces, internal sealed partial. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, sorry about the public properties in the interface, my mistake, wrote the code a bit too fast in VS.